# How do you embed a variable in a print() string and then call a function in python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

I'm working on python code that requires the user to input their name in theory it works perfectly but when i run the script I get these 3 lines as the output:

```
Please Enter your name

Your name will be saved as,  <built-in function input>
```

This is the code:

```
# Function for the user's name and then sends user to menu
print("Please Enter your name\n")
name = input
print("Your name will be saved as, ", name,)
menu()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking why you're seeing `<built-in function input>`? You're never calling `input`.

Comment: `name = input()` or even nicer `name = input('Enter your name\n')` should do.

Answer (score 0):

The line.   name = input.   saves what is the function 'input' you need to use the function "input" in the correct way

```
# Function for the user's name and then sends user to menu
print("Please Enter your name\n")
name = input()
print("Your name will be saved as, ", name,)
menu()
```